# Why does this simple regex work everywhere except html5 input pattern attribute?

Tags: javascript, html

[This HTML input](https://jsfiddle.net/qatt3rwt/) colours itself red to indicate the pattern has not matched when the value in the input is "1".

```
var inp = document .createElement ('input');
inp .pattern = '^\d+\.?\d*$';
document .getElementById ("foo") .appendChild (inp);
```

The regex `/^\d+\.?\d*$/` matches "1" when I test it elsewhere. Looks like it should too.

Why does the form element fail to match? (Firefox.)

Comment: Backslashes need to be escaped in string literals - not in HTML attributes or regex literals however.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

String representations, son.

Your usage of the pattern attribute is correct in that you are using string literals. From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input):

> The regular expression language is the same as JavaScript's. The
>   pattern is not surrounded by forward slashes.

However, in string literals you have to escape the `\` before the slash gets its own li'l interpretation in a string literal sense. If you escape it, it will be seen as an actual slash and *then* the whole pattern will be recognised by the RegExp engine as a special character.

```
var inp = document.createElement('input');
inp.pattern = '^\\d+\\.?\\d*$';
document.getElementById("foo").appendChild(inp);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/qatt3rwt/4/

Comment: @Christoph: I liked the first revision better :-)

Comment: Funny - yes, educational - meh...

Comment: @Christoph , Bergi Hopefully you're both happy now. :) (I was still editing when you edited the answer Christoph. I guess that'll teach me to first give the code, and then add an explanation.)